# ListView cellfactory: wrong font weight

Tags: java, listview, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Ich have a ListView cellfactory which should paint all items with the String "GHI" in bold. The problem is that even other (random) cells are painted in bold.

My code:

```
static class CellFactory extends ListCell<String> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (!empty) {

            super.setTextFill(Color.BLACK); // set TextColor Black

            if (item != null && item.equals("GHI")) {
                super.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");    //(1)
            }

        }       

        super.setText(item);

    }
}
```

Using the debugger, line (1) is only executed when item has the text "GHI".

Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: different lines in bold, only GHI should be bold]

I used Java 1.7.0_55 32Bit with JavaFX 2.2.55-b13 & Java 1.8.0_05 32Bit with JavaFX 8.0.5-b13. OS: Win7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you change the style of your cell when you find your string in there. But if not, you don't change the style of the cell back to the normal font.

Have a look at the code I posted below. If you comment out the line marked with (2), you will see, that the cell always stays fat.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());


            ListView<String> lv = new ListView<>();
            lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
            @Override 
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new CellFactory();
              }
            });

            ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            items.add("asd");
            items.add("fhg");
            items.add("GHI");
            items.add("tead");
            items.add("hoid");

            lv.setItems(items);

            root.setCenter(lv);

            Button btnAdd = new Button("add item");
            btnAdd.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(Event event) {
                    items.add(1, "test");
                }
            });

            root.setLeft(btnAdd);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    static class CellFactory extends ListCell<String> {

      @Override
      public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
          super.updateItem(item, empty);

          if (!empty) {

              super.setTextFill(Color.BLACK); // set TextColor Black

              if (item != null && item.equals("GHI")) {
                  super.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold");    //(1)
              }
          }     
          else{
                super.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: normal");    //(2)
          }


          super.setText(item);

      }

    }
}
```